# mpirun hangs without an error message or debug

Tags: mpi, intel-mpi

***ISSUE:*** MPIRUN hangs and does not display any error message even with I_MPI_DEBUG 100

***example:***
tried with any IMB-* benchmarks or even simple task as display hostname.

> mpirun -n 2 hostname
> it will just hang and never return any output or error.

Any idea what I may need to check or where to check for more info.

***OS info:***
Rocky Linux release 8.5 (Green Obsidian)

***MPI version:***
Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2019 Update 12
Copyright 2003-2021, Intel Corporation.

***strace hangs at:***

```
[pid 19786] sched_setaffinity(0, 8, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]) = 0
[pid 19786] nanosleep({tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffc04672b50) = 0
[pid 19786] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/system/node/node0/cpulist", O_RDONLY) = 6
[pid 19786] fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 19786] fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 19786] lseek(6, 0, SEEK_SET)       = 0
[pid 19786] lseek(6, 0, SEEK_SET)       = 0
```

Comment: If you are running any firewall, try disabling them.

Comment: Why use the openmpi tag if you use Intel MPI?

Comment: Try making an explicit hostfile, initially with only localhost.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, yes firewall is disabled.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, actually my first attempts were with a hostfile.

Comment: check name resolution. for example `getent hosts <your hostname>` and `getent hosts `your ip`. does `mpirun -np 1 hostname` works? if no, try `strace -f -- mpirun -np 1 hostname` and see where it hangs.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, name resolution is fine,

Comment: you tried both direct and reverse DNS/name resolution, right? btw, how many IP interfaces does your node have?

Comment: yes both ways you listed. it has one ip interface (eth0).
The strace hangs at :
[pid 19786] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/devices/system/node/node0/cpulist", O_RDONLY) = 6
[pid 19786] fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 19786] fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid 19786] lseek(6, 0, SEEK_SET)       = 0
[pid 19786] lseek(6, 0, SEEK_SET)       = 0

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue with Rocky 8.6 on a server with a AMD EPYC 74F3 CPU. Unfortunately I don't know the root cause either, but a simple `yum update` solved the issue for me.

Best regards,

Sebastian