# MPI Ubuntu -- mpirun hangs

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, message-passing

I am trying to build a cluster between 2 Ubuntu servers.
I installed mpi by running:

```
sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev
```

I can ssh through both servers without password and have created a share NFS between the 2 servers.
The issue is when I am trying to run a simple code to check if mpi is working:
For example on my master node, if I run:

```
   
   mpirun -np 2 hostname
```

or just

```
   mpirun
```

the command hangs indefinitely without any error message.

I read it might come from my firewall so I disabled it:

```
   sudo ufw status
   Status: inactive
```

but still the problem remains.

I used solution proposed here [sol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72885793/mpirun-hangs-without-an-error-message-or-debug)

and ran:

```
   strace -f -- mpirun -np 1 localhost
```

The progam hangs at:

> _flags=0}, 0) = 936 recvmsg(9, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12,
> msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=20, type=NLMSG_DONE, flags=NLM_F_MULTI,
> seq=1668671375, pid=1310460}, 0}, iov_len=4096}], msg_iovlen=1,
> msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 20 close(9)
> = 0 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_IP) = 9 connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6006),
> sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0 getsockname(9,
> {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(52429),
> sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [28->16]) = 0 close(9)
> = 0 socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_IP) = 9 connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(6006),
> sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr),
> sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0 getsockname(9, {sa_family=AF_INET6,
> sin6_port=htons(42893), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6,
> "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0 close(9)
> = 0 socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_TCP) = 9 setsockopt(9, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0 setsockopt(9,
> SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) = 0 connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET6,
> sin6_port=htons(6006), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6,
> "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = 0 getpeername(9,
> {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(6006), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0),
> inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, [124->28]) =
> 0 uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="dcilda1872", ...}) = 0
> access("/home/e177338/.Xauthority", R_OK) = 0 openat(AT_FDCWD,
> "/home/e177338/.Xauthority", O_RDONLY) = 10 fstat(10,
> {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=1120, ...}) = 0 read(10,
> "\1\0\0\ndcilda1872\0\00213\0\22MIT-MAGIC-CO"..., 4096) = 1120
> read(10, "", 4096)                      = 0 close(10)
> = 0 fcntl(9, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR) fcntl(9, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0 fcntl(9, F_SETFD,
> FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0 poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1)
> = 1 ([{fd=9, revents=POLLOUT}]) writev(9, [{iov_base="l\0\v\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", iov_len=12}, {iov_base="",
> iov_len=0}], 2) = 12 recvfrom(9, 0x558bd3c91e30, 8, 0, NULL, NULL) =
> -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) poll([{fd=9, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1

`

Would you have any idea ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: `sudo iptables -L` to confirm no firewall is running. how many network interface does each machine have?

Comment: I checked, no firewall is running. on each of the machine I have the following network interfaces:

Machine 1 --> Mater node where mpirun fails to run 
-bond0,
-br_c****6afb107,
-br-****,
-docker0,
-ens10***,
-ens10***,
-lo,
-5 veth***,

Machine 2 --> Worker Node: 
-br-1c2****
-docker0
-eno1
-lo
-only 1 veth***

Comment: Assuming `bond0` is the network that connects both nodes, try `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include bond0 --mca btl_tcp_if_include bond0 ...`

Comment: I observed that If I am connecting to the 2nd server ( Worker node) and run 
`mpirun -np 2 hostname` the command is executed without issue. The problem seems to come from the first server (master node)

Comment: I run the command: 
`mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include bond0 --mca btl_tcp_if_include bond0`
for different network interfaces. It still hangs.

I ran 
`strace -f -- mpirun -np 1 localhost` and I saw a connection refused error: 

`connect(9, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(6004), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
close(9)                                = 0
`
is it relevant ?

Comment: that could be related to X11. Try `unset DISPLAY` and see how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately It did not work neither. I found a work around. I built a docker container from my first server and then ssh to my second server from docker. MPI seems to work there.
Thanks for your time :)